# Using find to delete all files with a given name except the one with a given extension

Tags: unix, find, rm

I want to delete all files in a directory with a given name, except for one with a given extension. I.e. we have a directory with:

```
foo.txt foo.exe foo.jpg foo.png foo.something foo.somethingelse bar.jpg bar.exe
```

I want to get rid of `foo.txt foo.jpg foo.png foo.something foo.somethingelse`

BUT crucially I don't want to get rid of `foo.exe`

Is there an easy one liner to do this?

Thank you

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/193631/when-running-rm-rf-is-it-possible-to-exclude-certain-subdirectories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `!` inside a `find` command to exclude things, so something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f  -name "foo.*"  ! -name foo.exe  -exec rm '{}' \;
       -----------  -------  -------------  ---------------  ----------------
       in this dir   files    named foo.*   but not foo.exe  ...destroy them.
```

That should delete files matching `foo.*` in the current directory but leave `foo.exe` alone.

Comment: Won't `find` the way you have it now also search and find (and in this case delete) files in sub-directories?

Comment: @Levon: excellent point -- using maxdepth=1 will limit to the current directory.

Comment: Came back with: find . -type f  -maxdepth 1  -name "foo.*"  ! -name foo.exe  -exec rm '{}' \;
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: @JimBo: good point.  Re-ordering the arguments so that `maxdepth` comes before `type` should fix it.  (I've edited the answer to reflect that.)

Comment: Great! I can see myself coming back to this page a few times, it's quite a common task for me (and I have poor memory..)